# How to get files by GoPro3+ using GoPro.Hero library?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, gopro

this is my scenario:
I'm trying to use GoPro.Hero library(downloaded by [R1pper Page on Github](https://github.com/r1pper/GoPro.Hero)) in c#, but I cannot understand in which way download photos from GoProCamera..

```
var camera = Camera.Create<Hero3Camera>("10.5.5.9");
PowerUp(camera);
```

Isn't there a camera.Photos.Get(id) or similar thing?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at some of the source code. I found [this](https://github.com/r1pper/GoPro.Hero/blob/master/src/GoPro.Hero.Tests/GoProMediaBrowserTests.cs):

```
public void CheckDownloadImage()
    {
        var camera = GetCamera();
        var image=camera.Contents().ImagesAsync().Result.FirstOrDefault();
        if (image == null)
            Assert.Inconclusive("no image found");

        var response=image.DownloadAsync().Result.GetResponseStream();

        var memory = ReadToMemory(response);

        Assert.AreEqual(memory.Length, image.Size);
    }
```

This downloads the first image if there is one and checks if its download size is the same as the memory it uses.

And you can use something like this:

```
var images = camera.Contents().ImagesAsync().Result.ToList();
```

to get a list of all the images and download the ones you want accordingly.